# Differences between at_exit and END (upper case) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, keyword

What differences, if any, exist between the [Kernel#at_exit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) method and the [END](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-END) (all upper case) keyword? Is the latter merely a more Perlish way of doing things, and the former more Ruby-esque?

I tried doing `defined?(END {puts "Bye"})`, but got a syntax error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"The Ruby Programming Language" defines a minor difference in their behavior. `at_exit` can be called multiple times when within a loop and each iterated call will be executed when the code exits. `END` will only be called once when inside a loop.

> ...If an END statement is within a loop and is executed
>   more than once, then the code associated with it is still only registered once:

```
a = 4;
if (true)
  END { # This END is executed
  puts "if"; # This code is registered
  puts a # The variable is visible; prints "4"
}
else
  END { puts "else" } # This is not executed
end
10.times {END { puts "loop" }} # Only executed once
```

> The Kernel method at_exit provides an alternative to the END statement; it registers a
>   block of code to be executed just before the interpreter exits. As with END blocks, the
>   code associated with the first at_exit call will be executed last. If the at_exit method
>   is called multiple times within a loop, then the block associated with it will be executed
>   multiple times when the interpreter exits.

So, running:

```
2.times {
  END { puts 'END'}
  at_exit { puts 'at_exit' }
}
```

results in:

```
at_exit
at_exit
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `END` inside a method produces a warning, where `at_exit` doesn’t (although both still work):

```
def with_end
  END {puts 'with END'}
end

def with_at_exit
  at_exit {puts 'with at_exit'}
end

with_end
with_at_exit
```

output:

```
$ ruby foo.rb 
foo.rb:2: warning: END in method; use at_exit
with at_exit
with END
```

On a less practical level, [`END` is a language keyword](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/30d957fc612a51fab686af5c6c0dfb58b5e100a1/parse.y#L11047), and [`at_exit` is a method in the language](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/30d957fc612a51fab686af5c6c0dfb58b5e100a1/eval_jump.c#L145).